# PDF reader for symbian based mobile

Tags: pdf, symbian, nokia

I have Nokia 5233 mobile which has Symbian OS. I want to read PDF files on my mobile but there's no PDF reader available for this model. So I have decided to write my own PDF reader for my mobile but I have no clue where and how to start.

I would like to know

1) If there is any existing PDF reader (FREE) for symbian OS based mobiles?

2) Is there any PDF library / API which can help in writing PDF reader application?

3) Which library or API or technology is used by other open source PDF readers like CutePDF writer?

Please enlighten with your valuable inputs !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is very hard to find those kind of software for symbian. most of them comes with adobe reader trial edition. so the user must PAY for read pdf. well, that's odd, since most of the modern mobile OS comes with a native pdf reader.
take a look at http://www.mbrainsoftware.com/S60_3rd/Pdf/Pdf.htm I've tried the S60 5th edition version and it worked great for me.

actually, I believe that if you search for Poppler and DjvuLibre you will learn something about this subject.

Answer (score 1):

alternatereader. alternatereader is the opensource pdf reader for symbian hosted at sourcefourge. Here is the link http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/alternatedjvu/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install `AlternateReader`, from
http://sourceforge.net/projects/alternatedjvu/.

When I first tried installing AR on a Nokia 5230, equipped with Symbian S60,
I had some problems. 
After I had download it and unpack the archive, I tried to install the 9.4 version
(which is the version of my Symbian OS). But I received a "expired certificate" 
message.

---

**Some notices about the actual state of that software.**
Be aware that software doesn't work as it is, because of an "expired certificate" error 
thrown while you're trying to install it.

To get rid of this issue, you have to self-sign the software `before` you try to install 
it on your Symbian smartphone.
In this post

http://sourceforge.net/projects/alternatedjvu/forums/forum/1106481/topic/5173246

is explained in details what operations you have to do. 
Be aware that the Symbian SDK archive you should download is around 800 MB, and requires 3 GB of disk space, uncompressed.
After you've done that, you could try to install AR, by launching the file suited for 
your Symbian version.

If still any error occurs, you can follow the instructions provided in 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/alternatedjvu/forums/forum/1106482/topic/4718015,
so you should be able to install AlternateReader on your smartphone, finally.